# Function runs when button is clicked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a windows application using Python 3.x. I have my function here:

```
def deletefolder(): 
    currentUser=os.getlogin()
    folderPath="C:/users/{username}/appdata/roaming/Strategy Folder/Home/PROFIILE/CACHE".format(username=getpass.getuser())
    shutil.rmtree(folderPath)  
    os.rmdir(folderPath) 

delbtn = Button(deltab, text="Delete Cache", command=deletefolder)
delbtn.pack(pady=20)
```

When I go to test this it runs the "deletefolder" function right away. I want it to run when I click the button. I have tried to do an if/then statement and then have a label show up that it is complete. Instead it appears to keep running and gives an error the folder is no longer there (Because the code actually works to delete the folder). I have looked at several articles on here and it appears that the if/then might work best. But if it is running at the beginning when the program runs, that isn't good as it will take up resources running over and over.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The code you posted will not do what you say it does. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import messagebox:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

And Use try-except:

```
def deletefolder(): 
    try:
        currentUser=os.getlogin()
        folderPath="C:/users/{username}/appdata/roaming/Strategy Folder/Home/PROFIILE/CACHE".format(username=getpass.getuser())
        shutil.rmtree(folderPath)  
        os.rmdir(folderPath) 
    except Exception:
        messagebox.showinfo('Warning','Folder not exist')
```